# Ember.Select "value" doesn't stay in sync with binding

Tags: ember.js

I'm having an issue with Ember.Select, where the "value" binding doesn't stay in sync (goes back to the first value) when the "contents" binding changes.

Here is a JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kafod/1

Basically, changing the category changes the available values for the Ember.Select view, and it reverts back to the first available value.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Well the `Ember.Select` component needs to have one value selected so when you switch out the category, the `sort` field gets overwritten. A simple solution would be to have two sort fields, `sortAccomodations` and `sortEvents` as well as two `Ember.Selects` that you switch in your template depending on what category is selected.

See http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kafod/3/ for a working example.

```
{{#if categoryIsAccommodations}}
    <br />Sort by {{view Ember.Select content=sortOptions
    optionValuePath="content.key"
    optionLabelPath="content.text"
    value=sortAccomodations}}
{{/if}}
{{#if categoryIsEvents}}
    <br />Sort by {{view Ember.Select content=sortOptions
    optionValuePath="content.key"
    optionLabelPath="content.text"
    value=sortEvents}}
{{/if}}
```

---

Solution with one 'sort' value:

```
{{view Ember.Select content=sortOptions
   optionValuePath="content.key"
   optionLabelPath="content.text"
   value=sort}}
```

Controller:

```
  saveSorts: (->
    this.set('sortAccommodations', this.get('sort')) if this.get('category') is 'accommodations'
    this.set('sortEvents', this.get('sort')) if this.get('category') is 'events'
  ).observes('sort')

  categoryDidChange: (->
    this.set('sort', this.get('sortAccommodations')) if this.get('category') is 'accommodations'
    this.set('sort', this.get('sortEvents')) if this.get('category') is 'events'
  ).observes('category')
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kafod/5/

Comment: It's not possible for me to use two "sort" values, because it is contained in the query string. Can you think of another workaround?

Comment: Sure, you can 'save' the respective sort values when you switch category and 'reload' them when you switch back. See http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kafod/5/

Comment: That's definitely getting there, but there is still a bug I can't figure out. When you first load the JSBin, do the following: 1. Sort by "Name Ascending" 2. Change category to "Events" 3. Change category back to "Accommodations". The page is now in an inconsistent state, where the Ember.Select's value doesn't match "sort". Hmmm

Comment: It seems that when they're the same, something gets fudged up. Some code must not be firing somewhere.